# Animating coordinates in JavaScript - precalculated values vs. on-the-fly calculation

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

I'm working on a looping animation using JavaScript and HTML5 `<canvas>`. The animation consists of using canvas' `lineTo()` method to connect between 10 and 200 coordinates to create an animated shape. The animation is looping and has a duration of 10-20 seconds. Using `requestAnimationFrame()` I'm looking at around 60fps, each iteration of which the position of each coordinate is updated.

What is the most efficient way of approaching this type of animation?

**Approach 1 - on-the-fly calculations**

Currently I'm just calculating and updating the position of each point in each iteration of `requestAnimationFrame()`. The performance is OK, but on older devices I've noticed the CPU usage spiking and occasional rendering lags. The calculations are pretty basic geometrical manipulations.

**Approach 2 - pre-calculated positions**

I have been toying with the idea of pre-calculating each possible position that a pointcould have, and storing that in memory. Then during the `requestAnimationFrame()` loop, I can simply access the coordinates for each point and update its position. But I'm unsure of the performance implications and whether this would really make an impact.

I plan on testing approach 2 to see if there is a noticeable difference. But I'm curious if there is another approach I should consider? Is canvas even the right tool for the job here, or should I be looking at something like WebGL?

*** Edit: here are the calculation & canvas drawing functions so you have an idea of the computation run on each frame:

```
Animation.prototype = {

  ... the rest of the prototype setup ...

  // This function runs once per `requestAnmiationFrame()` call:
  updateNodes: function() {
    let progress = this.getProgressRadians(); // simple time offset

    // This loops over between 10-200 node objects, updating their positions
    this.nodes.forEach(node => {
      let offset =
        ((Math.sin(progress - node.numberOffset) + 1) / 2) *
        this.pixelWaveHeight;

      if (this.waveGrows) {
        offset =
          offset * (node.index / (this.nodes.length - 1)) * this.waveGrows;
      }

      if (this.waveAngleRadians) {
        offset +=
          Math.tan(this.waveAngleRadians) * this.spaceBetweenNodes * node.index;
      }

      let yValue = this.canvas.height - offset - this.pixelBaseHeight;

      node.y = yValue;
    });
  },

  // This function runs at the end of each `requestAnimationFrame()` call
  draw: function() {
    let ctx = this.canvas.ctx;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, this.canvas.height);
    this.nodes.forEach(node => {
      ctx.lineTo(node.x, node.y);
    });
    ctx.lineTo(this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    ctx.lineTo(0, this.canvas.height);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

Most of those properties are static, e.g. calculated once at the beginning and then just accessed:
`pixelWaveHeight` - Number
`waveGrows` - Number

Comment: 200 vectors is nothing, even for a TI calculator. If your code struggles to maintain 60FPS you probably do something wrong, and for us to judge, we'd need some code to look at. But anyway the bottleneck will probably be in the rendering step, not in your simple computation. `lineTo()` takes no time, `stroke()` on the other hand...

Comment: I was also surprised about the performance issue. Maybe I need to revisit the calculations and try to trim some fat. I just updated the question with the function that is called within the `requestAnimationFrame()` loop for context.

Comment: ... unfortunately you are doing it right. Your draw method is perfect, your update one could benefit from micro-optimisations here and there (e.g you could use 2 different iterators to make only one branching before the loop instead of one per node, you could also declare all the constants out of the loop to avoid access to inner props), but that would start to have a visible impact at 100K+ nodes only, not with just a few hundreds. Can you try to run a performance analysis from your dev tools on the slow machines to see where the bottleneck is?